# Search problem - JavaScript SubmitSearchRedirect - WSS 3.0

Tags: javascript, wss-3.0, windows-server, core-js

I am trying to search using the default search control from sharepoint.

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderSearchArea" runat="server">  
    <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="SmallSearchInputBox"/>    
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

But when using the search button it calls the Js function defined in `core.js` as bellow:

```
function SubmitSearchRedirect(strUrl)
{
        var frm=document.forms["frmSiteSearch"];

        if (frm==null)
        {
            if (typeof(MSOWebPartPageFormName) !="undefined")
                frm=document.forms[MSOWebPartPageFormName];
        }
        if (frm !=null)
        {
            var searchText=frm.elements["SearchString"].value; //ERROR IN HERE
            strUrl=strUrl+"?k="+escapeProperly(searchText);
            var searchScope=frm.elements["SearchScope"];
            if (searchScope !=null)
            {
                var searchScopeUrl=searchScope.value;
                if (searchScopeUrl)
                {
                    strUrl=strUrl+"&u="+escapeProperly(searchScopeUrl);
                }
            }
            frm.action=strUrl;
            frm.submit();
        }
}
```

It passes the 3 first ifs and generates an error on the line:

```
  var searchText=frm.elements["SearchString"].value;
```

with the error message:

```
TypeError: frm.elements.SearchString is undefined
```

This method is concatenating the queryString for the url bellow (if I access the method it works correctly), is a simple POST.

```
http://www.siteName/_layouts/searchresults.aspx?k=SEARCHINHERE&u=SCOPEADDRESS
```

Where k => query and u=> scope.

If somebody knows a workaround or how to solve this problem, please let me know.

Comment: Ok @Mike done !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was:

```
 <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderSearchArea" runat="server">
```

was not inside a form. I just added a form and it worked.